# python tuple print key name only

Tags: python

Can someone give me a tip on how to print just the name of all keys in a tuple? IE,

ralph
marley
sam

For example, how would I just print the name of each animal below and not the nested keys (if I have the terminology correct...) which list what type of animal and identifier..

```
animals = {'ralph': ('dog', 160101),
        'marley': ('dog', 160102),
        'sam': ('cat', 160103),
        'bones': ('dog', 160104),
        'bella': ('cat', 160105),
        'max': ('dog', 160106),
        'daisy': ('cat', 160107),
        'angel': ('cat', 160108),
        'luna': ('cat', 160109),
        'buddy': ('dog', 160110),
        'coco': ('dog', 160111),
       }

#dict(TUPLE)[key]
d = dict(animals)


for animal in animals.items():
    print(animal)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Theyre not tuples, thats a dictionary where the key is a name and the value is a tuple. You can use `animals.keys()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting this? Each iteration in `animals.items()` contains two different values, the key and the tuple. You should adress the key which is in the first index by adding the position `[0]` in your loop.

```
for animal in animals.items():
    print(animal[0])
```

Output:

```
ralph
marley
sam
bones
bella
max
daisy
angel
luna
buddy
coco
```

Comment: why fetch the valies if you don't want them ?

Comment: Because op stated `Can someone give me a tip on how to print just the name of all keys in a tuple? IE,

ralph marley sam` 
OP only wants a list with the keys.

Comment: I can read, thanks ;-) So I ask again: why do you fetch the values when you don't need them ? (hint: dicts are iterables).

Comment: Unless the code provided by OP returns an error, I always try to stay as close to it as possible. Of course `.keys()` would also work and so many other methods too. But given OP uses `.items()` and that does not raise any error, I'd rather stick with it. Do you feel we should prioritze optimization over OPs original Minimum reproducible example?

Comment: Even ` .keys()` is useless here - dicts already iterates on their keys (try `list({"foo": "bar"})`. And my priority on this kind of questions is to teach the readers (who are most often newbies) the correct _idiomatic_ way. Note I wrote "the readers" - SO is supposed to be knowledge base, not a forum, and the important point is not to solve the OP's problem "one way or another" but to provide the best possible answer _for everybody reading the question_.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly sure what you are attempting. Figured all of them in one go.

```py
>>> for name, animal in animals.items():
...     animal_type, the_number = animal
...     print(f'The {animal_type} {name} has the number {the_number}')
...
The dog ralph has the number 160101
The dog marley has the number 160102
The cat sam has the number 160103
The dog bones has the number 160104
The cat bella has the number 160105
The dog max has the number 160106
The cat daisy has the number 160107
The cat angel has the number 160108
The cat luna has the number 160109
The dog buddy has the number 160110
The dog coco has the number 160111
>>>
```

Two essential things here:

1. `dict.items()` yields the key and the value from a dictionary
2. `a, b = c` 'unpacks' the tuple `c = (0, 0)` into the names `a` and `b`, as in `a = c[0]` and `b = c[1]` (the tuple **must** have exactly two values)

Also worth mentioning that if you need the dictionary keys (rather than the values or both), `.keys()` yields every key in the dictionary. `.values()` does the same but for the values.

Comment: That's fine but it doesn't answer the question (and only works on recent py3 versions).

Comment: The OP did not specify a python version. fstring interpolation is probably the newer thing here, and is merely for illustrative porpoises.

Comment: The OP asked how to print the keys. Why give an example that fetches and prints the values too ?

Comment: The OP asked for the keys of a tuple ('name of all keys in a tuple'). Tuples have no keys. Dictionaries have keys, I have provided a comprehensive example of how to unpack values and keys from tuples and dictionaries. What exactly is the matter? I saw your answer, and even up voted it for the helpful links. The question is ambiguous to start.

Comment: I can only agree on the question being both confused and confusing - but the OP warned he wasn't sure about "terminology" and gave a clear unambiguous (well to me at least) example of the expected result ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes he did said that. That was why he was not downvoted or ignored (by me at least, nor you it seems). I gave the best answer I could, and will improve it further if needed.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone give me a tip on how to print just the name of all keys in a tuple?

Your  `animals` variable is [a `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), not a `tuple`. Its *values* are tuples. So your question is actually "how do I print the keys of a dict", which is simple:

```
print(animals.keys())
```

or if you want one per line:

```
print("n".join(animals)
```

or if you *really* want a for loop:

```
for key in animals: 
    print(key)
```

Note that we don't use the `.keys()` methods in the last two examples since `dict` are iterables and they do iter on their keys, not values.

You may want to read the fine manual (starting with the official tutorial) to learn more about "terminology" (which is very important indeed) and what standard datatypes have to offer.

Comment: This answer has more insight regarding iterability on dicts than the comments we were discussing! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
for animal in animals.keys():
    print(animal)
```

Comment: You don't need the call to `.keys()`.

Answer (score -1):

```
for key, value in animals.items():
    print(key)
```

Comment: why fetch the values if you don't want them ?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your `animals` tuple is actually a dictionary already, not a tuple. So calling `dict()` on it is redundant.

Furthermore, the entries to your dict `animals` are combinations of key/value pairs with the names of the animals as keys, and their species and number as their respective values in an actual tuple.

The `dict.items()` you used returns a list of tuples `(key, value)` which you can index as you would a list. So the following should work:

```
animals = {'ralph': ('dog', 160101),
            'marley': ('dog', 160102),
            'sam': ('cat', 160103),
            'bones': ('dog', 160104),
            'bella': ('cat', 160105),
            'max': ('dog', 160106),
            'daisy': ('cat', 160107),
            'angel': ('cat', 160108),
            'luna': ('cat', 160109),
            'buddy': ('dog', 160110),
            'coco': ('dog', 160111),
           }

for KeyAndValue in animals.items():
    print(KeyAndValue[0])
```

results in:

```
ralph
marley
sam
bones
bella
max
daisy
angel
luna
buddy
coco
```

you can iterate over just the keys in the following way too:

```
for name in animals.keys():
    print(name)
```

results in:

```
ralph
marley
sam
bones
bella
max
daisy
angel
luna
buddy
coco
```

Note that you don't actually have to call the `dict.keys()` method, as dictionaries are iterable by their keys by default. see [bruno desthuilliers answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58169726/1878539) for details and an example.

Comment: You don't need the call to `.keys()` here (dict naturally iterate on their keys), and iteration on (key, value) tuples is most often done using tuple unpacking ie `for key, value in yourdict.items():`, which saves the pain of subscripting the tuple.

Comment: Fair enough. Although the implicitness of that might confuse a beginner. I'll add a note pointing to your answer.

Comment: It's documented so it's not implicit, and this is the pythonic way so beginners WILL see it a lot in real code (well, beginners that are smart enough to read real code at least xD).

Comment: Implicit may not have been the right word. Invisibile might be better. I myself am a fan of knowing what's going on behind the screens. With just iterating over the dict it doesn't seem as clear to me. personal preference i guess.

Comment: I agree that what's "implicit" or "explicit" is partly a matter of habits and experience.